PostScript: Explain the difference between "newpath 0 0 moveto" and "newpath 0 0 moveto closepath"
Well I wanted to draw a "point" in PostScript (ghostscript 9.52) (using 1 setlinecap), so I tried (after 36 dup translate and 4 setlinewidth):
0 dup moveto stroke

But nothing appeared.
Instead
0 dup moveto closepath stroke

made the point.
However closepath shouldn't do anything in this situation, right?
Likewise
0 dup moveto 0 dup rlineto stroke

also produced a point.
What I don't understand is:
moveto sets the origin of the path (a point), so why can't I stroke it?
Both closepath and 0 dup rlineto don't move the point, but then I can stroke the point.
As I understand it the "path" is no longer "empty" after moveto, so stroke should do something IMHO.
As the PostScript Reference Manual describes "Stroking" as "The stroke operator draws a line along the current path.", I think a point should be drawn.
Could it be a bug in ghostscript?

How many edges would there be on a path containing only a "moveto"?  What does "closepath" do to the number of edges on a path?

I'd say moveto sets the starting point, so there should be one edge, and closepath sets a special mark that the last point is the first point also while adding an implicit lineto to the first point. So do you think a "point" has two edges?

If there were a moveto and a single lineto, how many edges would there be?  A closepath behaves like a special form of lineto, and adds one edge.  I would say that a moveto and closepath together produce one edge, and that a moveto by itself produces zero.

But according to pathforall there are two items already after moveto closepath (just as for moveto lineto). Also I think that moveto also defines the first point. The special case probably is that a moveto after a preceeding moveto just replaces the first point, but I suspect (I haven't checked) that pathforall will contain both still...

moveto specifically says "No new line segments are added to the current path". The closepath operator says "closes the current subpath by appending a straight line segment connecting the current point to the subpath’s starting point". So 'newpath 0 0 moveto' has no line segments' 'newpath 0 0 moveto closepath' has one line segment, exactly the same as any other lineto operation.  The behaviour seems correct to me.

@KenS Sounds convincing.
